# How to change the Visual Studio 2013 Product key

Tags: virtual-machine, visual-studio-2013, msdn

I have created a new VM with Windows 8.1 and VS2013 and all related updates. Now this VM was copied by other developers in order to avoid re-creating. Now how can they update the product key of VS2013 to ensure they are mapped to their MSDN subscription license?